# Writing multiple cookies to Java HTTP Response (HttpSlingServletResponse) not working

Tags: cookies, httpresponse, sling

I am trying to write multiple cookies to a SlingHttpServletResponse, however only the last cookie i write is visible in the browser.

Ex.
response.addCookie(new Cookie("foo", "bar"));
response.addCookie(new Cookie("lion", "bear"));
response.addCookie(new Cookie("cat", "dog"));

When I look at the cookies on my browser, the only cookie i see is the: "cat", "dog" cookie
If i switch the order, the last cookie is always the one that displays (so i dont think its something with a specific cookie).

The Java API indicates that you can call response.addCookie() any number of times to add any number of cookies.

Im not sure if this is a Sling specific issue (i dont think it would be) but it might be?

Comment: any luck on this? or the only solutions is stop using Sling? :D

Comment: I would check on newer versions of sling; this was posted 4 years ago and since updates  have been made to sling and jetty. I haven't run into this recently but then again I can't recall setting multiple cookies in recent memory (I probably have but can say for sure)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I suspect this is an issue of the underlying servlet container used.

By default Sling uses the Jetty 6 Container contained in the Apache Felix Http Bundle.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Would be interested in what you discover.

Comment: No, I guess people stopped using it 4 years ago :D